# Enviar Endereço do google maps de uma app em mensagem para o telemovel?

Tags: android, google-maps, sms

Estou a criar uma app em Android Studio, e estou com um problema.

A app contem o Google Maps onde nos mostra a nossa localização, mas o que realmente gostaria de fazer era, que ao carregar num botão, a nossa localização fosse enviada por SMS para um número de telemovel, será possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a API [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html):

```
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        enviarSMS("+551199999999", "Testando");
    }
});

...

//Enviando a mensagem

private void enviarSMS(String numero, String mensagem) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(numero, null, mensagem, null, null);
}
```

Ou você pode construir a mensagem no aplicativo padrão de SMS do aparelho:

```
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        enviarSMS("+551199999999", "Testando");
    }
});

...

//Enviando a mensagem

private void enviarSMS(String numero, String mensagem) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + numero));
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", mensagem);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```